# Child div overflowing parent div with negative margin top

Tags: css

I've added a negative margin to a child `div` inside a parent `div`. Everything works fine, until I added the negative margin and now the `title` div will not center but overflow. This might be a basic CSS error I'm not seeing, but no matter what I've tried so far, it hasn't done the trick.

I presume the problem lies that it sees the element bigger than it is, when it's not due to overflow. I've tried adding a `min-height` to the parent div, and then tried to center this with flexbox, but this did not center it in the middle, because it sees the parent element bigger than it is.

What would the best way be to fix this overflow so that the `title` `div` aligns perfectly in the center of the `container` `div`, but at the same time when the `content` div shows up they both align in the center of the `container` `div`? Thank you in advance for any help.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  [...container.querySelectorAll(".content")].forEach(ele => ele.classList.toggle("show"));
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .title {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 50px;
}

 .content {
    display: block;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgray;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: margin 2s;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.show {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  animation: slidein 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Some random title text.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your height of the parent div is `auto`. It is helpful when inner content height changes to accommodate for the new elements but a height with a  fixed value like 90px; will put your non expanded div exactly in center.

Keeping that in mind, this solution toggles a class on your parent div along with the expanded items.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 this.classList.toggle("containerExpand"); [...container.querySelectorAll(".content")].forEach(ele => ele.classList.toggle("show"));
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .title {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 50px;

}

 .content {
    position: relative;
   display: block;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgray;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: margin 2s;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.show {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  animation: slidein 2s;
}

.containerExpand{
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Some random title text.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the solution that you are looking for ? I cancelled `max-height: 0` from `content` and added `flexbox` to `title`

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  [...container.querySelectorAll(".content")].forEach(ele => ele.classList.toggle("show"));
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .title {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

 .content {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgray;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: margin 2s;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.show {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  animation: slidein 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Some random title text.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you suppose to have something like on screenshot

[image]

I'd suggest other CSS styling like:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
padding: 1rem;
background: white;
}
.container .title {
background: #90a4ae;
margin: -1rem -1rem 1rem -1rem;
padding: 1rem;
}
body {
background: #ddd;
margin: 1rem;
padding: 1rem;
max-width: 400px;
margin: 2rem auto;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.show {
transition: 0.5s;
max-height: 100%;
overflow: visible;
opacity: 1;
margin-top: 0px;
animation: slidein 2s;
}
```